# How do I fix this warning in my mx:request tag?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

I'm running an HTTPService with the following request:

```
<mx:request xmlns="">
    <view>{myViewStack.selectedChild.name}</view>
</mx:request>
```

The idea being to pass which child is selected on the viewstack to the php page, and then get that back so I can run some logic based on which child of the viewstack was selected at the time.

Everything seems to work, but I get the following warning:

> Data binding will not be able to detect assignments to "name".

This doesn't seem to be causing any trouble, but I know warnings usually mean that I am not following the best practice. How can I fix this? I don't really need this item to be bound, because the name will never change at runtime, but I don't know how else to include it in the request.

Wouter's given me a good workaround. But is there any way to call a variable in a request like this without binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to tell Flex that you're not interested in changes to `name`, and no way to flag a warning to be ignored.

As a workaround, you can extract the getting of the name into a separate function. Something like this:

```
<mx:Script>
    private function getName(container:Container):String {
        return container.name;
    }
</mx:Script>
...
<mx:request xmlns="">
    <view>{getName(myViewStack.selectedChild)}</view>
</mx:request>
```